# How to use .svc web service file in iPhone application

Tags: .net, iphone, web-services

I have .svc file of web service and now I want to use that in iPhone application. I tried to find out ways but couldn't find.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thank you,

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this links.

1  - http://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/using-soap-web-services-on-the-iphone

2  - http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/1954

3  - http://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient

Comment: If you can send me some sample, would be great.